# Still display form errors with -webkit-appearance: none?

Tags: html, css, forms, webkit

I have an input like this, inside a `<form>`:

```
<input type="checkbox" required>
```

Normally when I try to submit the form, it comes up with an error like this underneath the checkbox:
[image: "Please tick this box if you want to proceed."]

However, when I give it this line in the CSS, the error no longer appears:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

Is there any way to have it not appear like a checkbox but still come up with the error? Ideally I wouldn't want to use any additional JavaScript.

Comment: don't use `-webkit-appearance: none;` but instead use more CSS to change it's visual

Comment: I managed to get this working with @TemaniAfif 's suggestion, by using the `~` selector (`input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .checkbox`). However this question still remains open, as there might be a way to do so. Even if there isn't, I think the answer as to why will be interesting.